# Android: Keep RequestQueue running after app is closed

Tags: android

I have a RequestQueue on my Android app that uploads images to a server. I want those uploads to continue even after the app is closed through the recent apps menu, preferably with a notification that allows the user to cancel the uploads if they want. What's the best way to go about doing this that minimizes the chance of the process being killed prematurely (especially in regards to devices with aggressive app killing behaviours like Samsung devices)?

If it matters, my minSdkVersion is 21 and targetSdkVersion is 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use foreground [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) with sticky notification and potential options (action buttons) for canceling, thats the best way for achieve most reliable way for uploading data without interruption when something with GUI changes (app goes to background or even swiped out from recents)

still user may go to system Settings and Force kill app, this will kill your `Service` also - you can't prevent that, security reasons